# wp7 slider hangs up

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7

I am trying to use a slider control. It's just the simple control. Nothing fancy. But I run into an issue that is confusing me.

If I put the control on a test page (blank with nothing else) and navigate to it immediately after the app launches , I can slide it around perfectly. But if I navigate to another page first and then to the test page. I get a very weird behavior. The slider control moves in steps. It seems as if it hangs up or is losing focus.

I'm using wp7.1 and I've tested in the emulator and on the phone. Both give me the same result. I don't even know where to start solving this, but i definitely need a slider and for it to move smoothly.

Any ideas?

revised to include xaml:

```
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage 
x:Class="WP7ListBoxSelectedItemStyle.TestPage"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:phone="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Controls;assembly=Microsoft.Phone"
xmlns:shell="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Shell;assembly=Microsoft.Phone"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
mc:Ignorable="d" d:DesignWidth="480" d:DesignHeight="768"
FontFamily="{StaticResource PhoneFontFamilyNormal}"
FontSize="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeNormal}"
Foreground="{StaticResource PhoneForegroundBrush}"
SupportedOrientations="Portrait" Orientation="Portrait"
xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WP7ListBoxSelectedItemStyle"
xmlns:my="clr-namespace:colordata_controls;assembly=colordata_controls"
shell:SystemTray.IsVisible="True" xmlns:toolkit="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Controls;assembly=Microsoft.Phone.Controls.Toolkit">

<!--LayoutRoot is the root grid where all page content is placed-->
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="Transparent">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <!--TitlePanel contains the name of the application and page title-->
    <StackPanel x:Name="TitlePanel" Grid.Row="0" Margin="12,17,0,28">
        <TextBlock x:Name="ApplicationTitle" Text="IPO" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextNormalStyle}"/>
        <TextBlock x:Name="PageTitle" Text="Test" Margin="9,-7,0,0" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextTitle1Style}"/>
    </StackPanel>

    <!--ContentPanel - place additional content here-->
    <Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Grid.Row="1" Margin="8,17,16,-17">
        <Slider Height="84" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,10,0,0" Name="slider1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="460" />
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

here is a link to a video of it in action in the emulator. https://vimeo.com/36428677

Comment: Are you sure there is NOTHING in the control? This behavior happens you have a slider in a pivot control

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so, I still don't know why the slider sticks that way, but in order to keep moving forward I created my own slider. Hopefully this code helps someone else.

xaml:

```
<UserControl 
x:Name="userControl" 
x:Class="controls.pSlider"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
mc:Ignorable="d"
d:DesignWidth="76" d:DesignHeight="400" Background="Gray" Foreground="White">

<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="Transparent" MouseMove="LayoutRoot_MouseMove" MouseLeftButtonDown="LayoutRoot_MouseLeftButtonDown">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="10"/>
        <RowDefinition/>
        <RowDefinition Height="10"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Rectangle x:Name="colorBar" Margin="20,6" Width="10" Fill="{Binding Background, ElementName=userControl}" Grid.Row="1"/>
    <Grid x:Name="g_container" Grid.Row="1" Margin="0,1,0,13">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition/>
            <RowDefinition Height="0"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid x:Name="g_thumb" Height="0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Grid.Row="1">
            <Canvas Height="0" VerticalAlignment="Top">
                <Path Data="M0,0 L1,0 L1.2,0.5 L1,1 L0,1 z" Margin="0" Stretch="Fill" UseLayoutRounding="False" Width="33" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" StrokeThickness="0" Fill="{Binding Foreground, ElementName=userControl}" Height="12" d:LayoutOverrides="VerticalAlignment"/>
                <Path Data="M0.3,0.5 L0.5,0 L1.5,0 L1.5,1 L0.5,1 z" Margin="0" Stretch="Fill" UseLayoutRounding="False" Width="33" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" StrokeThickness="0" Fill="{Binding Foreground, ElementName=userControl}" Height="12" Canvas.Left="43" d:LayoutOverrides="VerticalAlignment"/>
            </Canvas>
        </Grid>
        <Rectangle x:Name="r_lifter" Margin="0" Grid.Row="2" Height="188" StrokeThickness="0"/>
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

code:

```
namespace controls {
public partial class pSlider : UserControl {

    public event RoutedEventHandler ValueChanged;

    public static readonly DependencyProperty MaxProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register("Maximum", typeof(double), typeof(pSlider), new PropertyMetadata(100.0));

    public double Maximum {
        get { return (double)GetValue(MaxProperty); }
        set { SetValue(MaxProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty MinProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register("Minimum", typeof(double), typeof(pSlider), new PropertyMetadata(0.0));

    public double Minimum {
        get { return (double)GetValue(MinProperty); }
        set { SetValue(MinProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty ValueProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register("Value", typeof(double), typeof(pSlider), new PropertyMetadata(50.0));

    public double Value {
        get { return (double)GetValue(ValueProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ValueProperty, value); }
    }

    public pSlider() {
        InitializeComponent();
        Loaded += new RoutedEventHandler(pSlider_Loaded);
    }

    void pSlider_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {

        if (Value > Maximum)
            Value = Maximum;
        else if (Value < Minimum)
            Value = Minimum;

        double min = 0;
        double max = g_container.ActualHeight;

        r_lifter.Height = Value / (Maximum - Minimum) * (max - min);

    }

    private Point Position;

    private void LayoutRoot_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e) {
        Point newPosition = e.GetPosition((UIElement)sender);

        double delta = newPosition.Y - Position.Y;
        double temp = r_lifter.Height - delta;

        if (temp > g_container.ActualHeight)
            r_lifter.Height = g_container.ActualHeight;
        else if (temp < 0)
            r_lifter.Height = 0;
        else
            r_lifter.Height = temp;

        double min = 0;
        double max = g_container.ActualHeight;

        Value = r_lifter.Height / (max - min) * (Maximum - Minimum);
        Value = Math.Floor(Value);
        RoutedEventHandler handler = ValueChanged;
        if (handler != null)
            handler(this, e);


        Position = e.GetPosition((UIElement)sender);
    }

    private void LayoutRoot_MouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e) {
        Position = e.GetPosition((UIElement)sender);
    }

}
```

}